# Using jquery.layout, How to resize the container's height when resizing north pannel's height

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using [jQuery UI.Layout Plug-in](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/index.cfm),and the html code struct like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="pane ui-layout-center">Center</div>
    <div class="pane ui-layout-north">North</div>
    <div class="pane ui-layout-south">South</div>
    <div class="pane ui-layout-east">East</div>
    <div class="pane ui-layout-west">West</div>
</div>
```

when i resize the north panel's height, the center panel's height will change,and the container's height will be the same.

But i need the center pannel's height to be the same,and the container's height to change.how can i do?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour It will help you improve this question. We will need a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: How does what you want differ from the behavior of this demo? http://layout.jquery-dev.com/demos/container.html